# Modify Antd Date/Rangepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

How can I modify the Datepicker component of AntD? I want it to look like this.
Is this possible by just clicking the datepicker input? or is there other workaround for this?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play around with the prop `renderExtraFooter` and add styles to place it on top

#### Example:

**Code:**

```
<Space direction="vertical" size={12}>
    <RangePicker
        renderExtraFooter={
            () => {
                return <Radio.Group name="radiogroup" defaultValue={1}>
                            <Radio value={1}>Start of Evaluation</Radio>
                            <Radio value={2}>End of Evaluation</Radio>
                       </Radio.Group>
                }
        }
    />
</Space>
```

**Style:**

```
.ant-picker-panels {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.ant-picker-footer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #303030 !important;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Example]

Comment: I'll need to add the radio buttons on top of the rangepicker

Comment: Wew! I never knew this will fix using CSS alone! Thank you so much!